# Solution for local “database” containing huge text and .SQL files

Tags: mysql, search, grep, database

I have a few hundred gigabytes of text data contained within a single directory tree. This data is comprised of both very large text files and a few MySQL database dumps (which for the most part, of course, function as text files when outside of the DBMS they came from). The structure of the data within the text files varies wildly, with some being single record per line, some having columns and all kinds of column separators, and a few that even appear to be JSON.

My usual method of searching this large but primitive database is to do a `grep` at the parent folder, but the database is now large enough that a single `grep` command can take as much as 30 minutes.

For this reason, I'm long overdue a move to a proper database solution.

All the data is stored on my local machine and I will be the only user, hence my requirements for a solution would be as follows:

- That I can point it to the parent directory to index the contents of all the text files in it, giving me the ability to search through them as fast as possible
- That I don't have to learn SQL or another language just to search the database: a GUI and/or CLI is fine
- That I don't have to setup and run an entire server just to access it (unless there is no such thing as a serverless DBMS and this is absolutely inescapable)
- A nice but not strictly necessary bonus: that I can search through files using their columns, even when between them they have inconsistent separators

Does a database management solution that would fulfil those needs exist, or am I asking for too much here?

Apologies for any sort of naivete or false assumptions in this question; databases are simply something my needs have forced me to look into, rather than anything that I necessarily know much about.

Answer (score 0):

It might take a huge jump in complexity to have a database to handle the variety of data you appear to have.

Although the SQL statements you would need to query the resulting database would be fairly simple, getting your existing files into an appropriate format for loading to the database with reasonable / useful columns would be pretty complex.

So, assuming you mostly want things faster now:

If your data files have reasonably accurate file name extensions, such as `*.txt` and `*.sql` or whatever the MySQL dump file names are, you could have a script do a few `find` commands in parallel starting at the parent directory, one `find` command per file name extension,  and then run an appropriate command based on the extension.

Something like this untested shell script:

(The `&` at the end is the magic to run the two find/grep commands in the background)

```bsh
STRING_TO_FIND=$1
DIR_BASE=/home/brian/docdump
cd $DIR_BASE

# Assuming there is a subdirectory in above directory named work
TXT_GREP_OUT=${DIR_BASE}/work/grep_txt.log
SQL_GREP_OUT=${DIR_BASE}/work/grep_sql.log

find $DIR_BASE -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep "$STRING_TO_FIND" /dev/null {} \; > $TXT_GREP_OUT &
find $DIR_BASE -type f -name '*.sql' -exec grep "$STRING_TO_FIND" /dev/null {} \; > $SQL_GREP_OUT &
```

Comment: Is this really the fastest solution for my needs? I haven't tested yet, but I can't see how using `find` instead would be significantly faster than using `grep`, or at least not as fast as a DBMS might make it. Which of my requirements in particular do you think a DBMS would struggle with? Is it that DBMSes can only handle one type of data, or that they can't be set to work on a given directory tree, or can't be used without a server, or something else? Even if the ability to search by column is out of the question, I would have thought a DBMS would be able to handle text without a problem.

Comment: Well, faster in that you could run several at the same time, and some of the find/grep threads may run quick.  And you could launch several in the background starting in different subdirectories.